# creating bash script to add additional IPs, cent OS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to create this bash script to add add IPs that are in a text file on the server.

the file, myfile.txt has 1 IP per line and the script test.sh includes

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while read line
do
 filename=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:$count
 echo
"DEVICE=eth0:$count\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=$line\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255"
> filename
 count=$((count+1))
 done < myfile.txt
```

When I run ./test.sh
I get

```
./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:0\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.235\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255:     command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:1\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.236\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:2\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.237\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:3\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.238\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:4\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.239\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:5\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.240\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:6\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.241\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:7\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.242\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found

./test.sh: line 8: DEVICE=eth0:8\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=95.211.140.243\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255: command not found
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Do not separate `echo` from `"DEVICE=eth0:$count\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=$line\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255"` and `> filename`. These 3 lines should really be 1 line. Also, do not create the file `filename`. What you really want is `> $filename`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, had to change echo to printf as it was not adding a new line, thanks alot